# JavaScript syntax issue I cannot resolve

Tags: javascript

```
   function ActiveTab()
   {   
   var a= $find("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tcEmployee_ClientState").value;
    alert("First line");
    var add=document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAddRecord");
        alert("after add");
     var update=document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnUpdateRecord"); 
        alert("after update");
      var delet= document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DeleteRecord");
            alert("after del");
        if(a == 0)
        { 
                alert("if 0");  
            add.WebForm_PostBackOptions = "Insertion";
            update.WebForm_PostBackOptions = "Insertion";
            delet.WebForm_PostBackOptions = "Insertion";
        } 
        else if(a == 1)
        {
            alert("if 1");
            add.WebForm_PostBackOptions = "Insertion1";
            update.WebForm_PostBackOptions = "Insertion1";
            delet.WebForm_PostBackOptions = "Insertion1"; 
        }
        else  
        {
                alert("else");
            add.WebForm_PostBackOptions = "Insertion2";
            update.WebForm_PostBackOptions = "Insertion2";
            delet.WebForm_PostBackOptions= "Insertion2";   
        }  
  }
```

What is problem with my code I receive `}` and `;` missing error. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

should be `getElementById`:

```
var add = document.setElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAddRecord");
```

and missing `=`:

```
var delet document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DeleteRecord");
```

Comment: it was my mistake but with getElementById also have same error

Comment: i have edited and now u check it.

Comment: line 9. below alert("after update");

Comment: still getting } expected error

Comment: code looking good. perhaps the problem is from `WebForm_PostBackOptions`?

Comment: i want to set validation group in javascript what it will be in javascript i mean valitaion group property in javascript

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP.NET. but this may help you:

`function WebForm_PostBackOptions(eventTarget, eventArgument, validation, validationGroup, actionUrl, trackFocus, clientSubmit)`

it's certainly a function, so you can't assign a string to it.

Comment: u mean to say that i must write like add.WebForm_PostBackOptions(validationGroup) = "Insertion2";
 or some thing else

Comment: if u say yes then this also did not worked for me

Comment: I think you should call the `WebForm_PostBackOptions(null,null,null,'Insertion2')` instead.
Try putting relevant variable into `validation`, `actionUrl`.
My suggestion can be wrong. I should leave it to ASP.net experts to answer for u.

Comment: <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnAddRecord" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAddRecord" src="buttons/buttons_58.gif" alt="Add Record" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnAddRecord&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;Insertion&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" />                         js code for that button on which i want to set property

Comment: try single quote: **EDIT**:
`<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnAddRecord" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAddRecord" src="buttons/buttons_58.gif" alt="Add Record" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnAddRecord','', true, 'Insertion', '', false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" />`

Comment: what would be js code to set button validation group

Comment: maybe refer to this?
http://forums.asp.net/t/1028478.aspx/1?How+to+call+Page+Validate+using+javascript

Comment: y u gave negative reputation????